# ViewsLifeTime is null in subsites

Tags: search, sharepoint-rest-api

When I'm doing a search for **ViewsLifeTime** with Rest API for a specific page in the **root site (site collection)** everything is fine, like below query:

```
https://site.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27Path=https://site.com/Pages/sample.aspx%27
```

[image]

but when changing path to a page in **subsite** viewsLifeTime is **null**

```
https://site.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27Path=https://site.com/subsite/Pages/sample.aspx%27
```

[image]

all options Queryable, Retrievable, Sortable, Safe for Anonymous in Managed Properties for ViewsLifeTime is enabled.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you checking this on SharePoint Online? Is the page in subsite is classic web part page or Modern site page?

Comment: sharepoint on premise and classic webpart page ,@GaneshSanap

Comment: Have you tried only till subsite URL instead of whole page URL ?

Comment: only subsite URL ( https://site.com/subsite/ ) have viewsLifeTime , not pages. do you have a solution? @Ravi